# Which version of hadoop I need for running nutch?

Tags: hadoop, version, nutch

I'm pretty confused about what version and distribution of hadoop I can use with nutch 1 and nutch 2.
Do I need "plain" Apache hadoop or can use e.g. Cloudera? In any case I would like to know dependencies of versions of nutch and hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

If you get Nutch 1.8, Hadoop will be bundled with the Nutch distribution. It has Hadoop 1.2.